# Immersive fullscreen on Android 11, show navigation bar with soft keyboard

Tags: android

The navigation bar won't appear with the soft-keyboard when in immersive fullscreen on Android 11, but on api <  30 the nav bar will show with the soft-keyboard.

```
private void hideSystemUI() {

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 30) {

        @SuppressLint("WrongConstant") final int flags = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;

        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(flags);

        final View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        decorView.setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener(new View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int i) {
                if((i & View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN) == 0) {
                    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(flags);
                }
            }
        });

    } else {

        getWindow().setDecorFitsSystemWindows(false);
        WindowInsetsController controller = getWindow().getInsetsController();

        if (controller != null) {
            controller.hide(WindowInsets.Type.systemBars());
            controller.setSystemBarsBehavior(WindowInsetsController.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE);

        }
    }

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
        getWindow().getAttributes().layoutInDisplayCutoutMode =
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.LAYOUT_IN_DISPLAY_CUTOUT_MODE_SHORT_EDGES; }
}
```

This is using a Searchview in Android 11 which brings up the soft-keyboard:

[image]

How can I make the navigation bar appear when the soft-keyboard appears?